# How do I find the average of the ordertime column per each vendor I created in my first view

Tags: mysql, view

[Results from first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjXI3.png)

[My second view which gives me an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUmYZ.png)

I get Error Code: 1054, Unknown Column "V1.V_Name in 'on clause'

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vendor_order_times;

CREATE VIEW vendor_order_times AS
 SELECT
    v.V_NAME as 'Vendor Name',
    DATEDIFF(o.O_ARR_DATE, o.O_DATE) as ordertime
    FROM vendor v 
      JOIN product p ON v.V_ID = p.V_ID
      JOIN line l ON p.P_ID = l.P_ID
      JOIN orders o ON l.O_ID = o.O_ID
    GROUP BY o.O_ID
    ORDER BY v.V_ID;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vendor_shipping_stats;

CREATE VIEW vendor_shipping_stats AS
  SELECT 
    v.V_NAME as 'Vendor Name', 
    ROUND(AVG(vot.ordertime),1) as 'Vendor: Avg Ship Times',
    QueryAuthor() as 'Query Author'
  FROM vendor v
    JOIN vendor_order_times as vot on vot.V_NAME = v.V_NAME 
  GROUP BY v.V_NAME
  ORDER BY `Vendor: Avg Ship Times` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `vendor_order_times` view you renamed the `V_NAME` field to `'Vendor Name'`, therefore either you need to use this name in the 2nd view as well, or you ned to remove the alias in the `vendor_order_times` view.